# How to add a copy link to the current Page in Django to be copied for Sharing

Tags: django

I am trying to add share button to capture the current page link in Django so that the user can use it for sharing, simply when the button is clicked it copies the current link

Here is the template for a post page created

```
                Copy Link to Share<a href=""><i class="fas fa-share-square"></i></a>
```

Thank you

Comment: `request.build_absolute_uri()` will generate an absolute URL to the current page

Comment: @IainShelvington I am unsure how it works, should I add it first to the views.py ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure whether Django has a method built-in, but Javascript definitely has one. Just do something like:

```js
function getURL() {
    alert("The URL of this page is: " + window.location.href);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="getURL();">Get Page URL</button>
```

This code segment should return the current URL with the query (things after the `?` mark)